# developer setting for Samsung The Premiere Triple Laser 4K Smart Projector

Tags: settings, developer-tools, projector, samsung

can anyone help

does anyone know how to open the developer setting for The Samsung Premiere Triple Laser 4K Smart Projector

i have a samsung tv and understand to go to the smart hub to do this however the projector does not have this feature.

ive searched high and low and been unable to find a solution